# GPG Public Key changes after removing master key

Tags: encryption, cryptography, pgp, gnupg, openpgp

Why does my gpg public key change after removing my master key (leaving just my subkeys) from the gpg key ring? I'm doing this so i can move my daily use keys (subkeys) to my online machine while leaving my master key completely offline. What i'm finding is that when i look at my public key (gpg --export -a john.doe@example.com) with my master key present, the public key is completely different than it is after i remove the master key and just have the subkeys present. Why is this?

Here is the procedure i followed to remove the master key and leave just the subkeys:

```
$ gpg -a --export-secret-subkeys john.doe@example.com > secret_subkeys.gpg
$ gpg --delete-secret-keys john.doe@example.com
$ gpg --import secret_subkeys.gpg
```

Comment: What do you mean with "different"? If you don't want to publish your key here, you probably should create a test key pair to demonstrate the issue (edit your question to add more information). I'm voting for closure because it is "unclear what you're asking" for the moment.